# iOS IAP non-consumables pay now and download later

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app which offers quite large files for purchase and download. I want to set up a system where the users can pay for their purchase and manually download the content at a later time. Is this possible? I tried a few things but there seems to be no way to create a proper `SKPaymentTransaction` object or a `SKDownload` object. Is there a good way to do this without hosting on a server other than Apple's own?